# Lua gsub chars '(' and ')' fails

Tags: lua, gsub, lua-patterns

For some reason only the open and close bracket wont work, all others are fine.

```
RequestEncoded = string.gsub(RequestEncoded, '<', ' ')
RequestEncoded = string.gsub(RequestEncoded, '>', ' ')
RequestEncoded = string.gsub(RequestEncoded, '"', ' ')
RequestEncoded = string.gsub(RequestEncoded, '\'', ' ')
RequestEncoded = string.gsub(RequestEncoded, '\\', ' ')
--  RequestEncoded = string.gsub(RequestEncoded, '(', ' ') keeps failing
--  RequestEncoded = string.gsub(RequestEncoded, ')', ' ')
--  RequestEncoded = string.gsub(RequestEncoded, "\x28", " ") --keeps failing
--  RequestEncoded = string.gsub(RequestEncoded, "\x29", ' ')
--  RequestEncoded = string.gsub(RequestEncoded, '\050', ' ') --keeps failing
--  RequestEncoded = string.gsub(RequestEncoded, '\051', ' ')
```

Answer (score 5):

`)` and `(` are special characters that form a capturing group in a Lua pattern.

You need to escape them when they are outside of square brackets, `[...]`, to match literal parentheses. You need to escape them with `%`.

```
string.gsub(RequestEncoded, '%(', ' ')
string.gsub(RequestEncoded, '%)', ' ')
```

However, since you are using the same replacement pattern in all the subsequent `gsub` calls, you may simplify your code to

```
RequestEncoded = string.gsub(RequestEncoded, '[<>"\'\\()]', ' ')
```

Note that here, `()` are inside a bracket expression and do not need escaping.

See [Lua patterns](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html) docs:

> Some characters, called magic characters, have special meanings when used in a pattern. The magic characters are
>
> `( ) . % + - * ? [ ^ $`